# Android to Arduino server communication

Tags: javascript, http, network-programming

I'm a long time lurker, first time poster. I'm working on a small home automation project using an Android device (Jelly Bean 4.3) and Arduino Uno w/ Wi-Fi shield. So far I have set up my arduino as a web server and can access the page via an IP address i'm given after the arduino connects to my home network. I have coded the arduino so that I can turn on and off an LED by using commands like: http://IP Address/H (turns the Relay on) and http://IP Address/L (turns the Relay off). The end goal is to use what I have learned to control my lights/water heater etc. I would like to be able to use my android device to send HTTP post requests to these exact IP addresses in an application so that I don't have to access these commands by my desktop. I am using Android Studio to write my application, and have been able to create a UI that has two buttons (ON and OFF). What would be a viable way to access these IP addresses? Sockets seem like a steep learning curve as I have little experience in JAVA programming. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are the simplest example of http call from android:

```
String link = "http://www.google.com";
URL url = new URL(link);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.connect();
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
String webPage = "",data="";
while ((data = reader.readLine()) != null){
    webPage += data + "\n";
}
```

this tutorial is very helpful and straight forward:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_network_connection.htm

Comment: I tried to implement this string method into my app, but keep receiving "unhandled exception" errors. I then tried to bypass these errors by surrounding them with try/catch methods. The code compiles and loads onto my device, but upon opening the app, it crashes immediately. What am i doing wrong?